# Displaying alternative content (image/text) when flash is not available? for an iframe page from extra source which contains flash

Tags: html, flash, iframe, fallback, object-tag

I have this link: http://www.qe.com.qa/QECharts/English/Trading%20Company%20Graph/CompanyTradeGraph.html?CompanyCode=QIMD which I want to show it on a new website to display stock price of the same company. I was able to achieve this by iFrame or Object html tag.

The content of this link seems to be javascript controls on the top and dynamic Flash graph underneath.

My problem is that when viewing this iframe/object on iPhone or none-flash browsers, a white space appears under the JS controls in the place of the flash graph ONLY (which is logical because of no flash).

Is it possible to show an image (fallback) on this part of the iframe content (flash graph) when no flash installed?

I searched several forums but with no luck.

Any help, please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the folowing method:

in your main page add the iframe and also add that image 
give the image style display none
and from your style add specefic style for mobile size and give the iframe display none and for the image display block

here is the sample code to understand what i mean

```
<div class="hide-on-mobile"><iframe>your iframe</iframe></div>
<div class="show-on-mobile" style="display:none"><img src=""></div>

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px){
        .hide-on-mobile{display:none}
        .show-on-mobile{display:block!}
}
```

or you need to use javascript to check if there is flash or no and display your image if there is no flash . check this link http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/

Comment: This solution wouldn't work on PC browsers with no Flash installed. I am looking for a way to have fallback content if no flash is available.

Comment: in this case you need to use javascript to check if there is flash or no and display your image if there is no flash . check this link http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/

Comment: Super! This is exactly what I am looking for! 

You are so helpful!

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to be able to vote as I am new to this forum (inactive old account). Will make it by the time I am eligible to vote :)